# How to get all items where a nested item are []?

Tags: graphql

So I have this structure

```cs
public class Device 
{
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public ICollection<Site> Sites { get; set; }
}
```

And I can query it like this np

```
    {
      devices  {
        nodes{
          id
          Sites
        }
      }
    }
```

results are that **some** devices have no Sites, just [] (expected and no problem)

What I want to do is to **get all devices that have Sites as []**

I have tried the syntaxes I could think of with both were and filtering so hoping somebody can fill me in.

Answer (score 0):

OK 2 min after posting my question I figured this out and here is basically the answer.

```
{
 devices(where: {sites:{any:false}}) {
   nodes{
     name
       sites {
          id
          name
        }
      }
    }
}
```